# Accessing resources file in Java Program on command prompt

Tags: java, file

I created a project on IntelliJ ide, and my program reads input files which I have stored in folder called resources. So in my project folder I have src and resources. In the java file inside src, I am reading input file with the string "resources/file.txt" . On IntelliJ it reads the files perfectly fine, but when I compile and run it on cmd, it can not read it. Do I need more specification on the path of the .txt files? And if so, then how?

Comment: Not clear if you're talking about `src/main/resources`, or just some resources folder placed elsewhere in the project... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html

Comment: Also see https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/

Comment: myProject contains src and resources as seperate directories.

Comment: Okay... But a "standardized project layout" consists of `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources` is where files ought to be placed to be read on the classpath

Comment: And if you're just running `java` on the CMD, you must explicitly provide `-cp` to specify the classpath of where to read the file... Otherwise, you're trying to read a file *relative to the Java class file*